# <asp:Menu> affected by jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-webcontrol

I have an asp:Menu control in an ASP.NET 4.5 web form application.

The moment I added a reference to jquery-1.7.1.js, drop down menu items go haywire.  They show up in a far corner of the page and is white text on white background.  The result is the same in IE10 and Chrome.

(The RenderingMode for the Menu control is set to Table as List won't work in ASP.NET 4 and later.)

What could be happening and how can I solve this problem?  Thanks

Comment: How about using the [CSS Friendly Control Adapters](http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/) to have the menu rendered in resonable HTML tags?

Comment: Thanks.  This is an existing web site in production and we are just adding jQuery to a couple of pages.  Is the CSS Friendly Control Adapters just an add-on without having to change the existing ASP controls?

Comment: Yes, it is something you do not have to change your code for.

Comment: I tried this and am still tweaking after a few hours.  The drop down menu is in the right place, but the colors and looks are all different.  I notice the use of AspNet-Menu-xxx style classes but can't find their definitions.  Are these meant for me to customize?

Comment: I found my problem.  It was not because of the inclusion of the jQuery script file.  It was because I used <script src=...  `/>` instead of <script ... >`</script>`.  I am puzzled why that caused drastic changes in the rendering.